# apt-get not installing anything linux server

Tags: linux, dependencies, apt-get

Anything with apt-get install is giving following error

> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>   The
>   following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    openssh-server : Depends:
>   openssh-client (= 1:6.0p1-4) but 1:6.0p1-4+deb7u2 is to be installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or
>   specify a solution).

If i try to install apt-get -f install it give following error

```
reparing to replace openssh-server 1:6.0p1-4 (using .../openssh-server_1%3a6.0p1-4+deb7u2_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement openssh-server ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a6.0p1-4+deb7u2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of `./usr/sbin/sshd' before installing new version: Operation not permitted
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a6.0p1-4+deb7u2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

sudo apt-get update also not working completely.  Suggestion please
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get -f install` like it suggested? This usually happens when a dependency wasn't met for whatever reason and it needs to get the database in a consistent state.

Comment: @Bandrami i have update question with output of apt-get -f install ... Thanks for reply

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

If you are not logged in as root (as I'm assuming), you should put `sudo` before adding/removing packages to the system.

If that doesn't work, run these commands:

```
chattr -i /usr/bin/sshd
chattr -a /usr/bin/sshd 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

If that doesn't work, you can also go to `/var/lib/dpkg/info` and `/var/cache/apt/archives` to delete anything with a name close to `openssh-server`. Then, run the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

pd: this is quite complex, so not having access to the system means a lot of "try and fail" :(

Comment: its giving same errors as i have mention above... Thanks for reply

Comment: i am running these commands on server via ssh , i might that i might not lost ssh to server after installing openssh-server or is it OK

Comment: I just can't understand your sentence. Could you please rewrite it another way?

Comment: if i delete anything with a name close to openssh-server will it affect my ssh login on server ? because i am on the server

Comment: Ah, OK. No, no problem. You will not delete any of the binaries you are actually using, so no problem

Comment: I'm glad it finally worked. Keep this question bookmarked, because this kind of things can happen quite frecuently. Keep it on!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I tried all of this and more, and not one of the methods worked. So I tried to remove openssh-client, then install openssh-server and that worked for me.

Comment: 'sudo apt-get remove openssh-client' worked for me, but for some reason it also removed 'snapd'. But atleast 'sudo apt-get install openssh-server' worked after this.